# inequality involving integral $f(2n)\leq W_n-F(n)\leq f(n)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have  a question.

$f$ is a decreasing function on the positive real numbers.

Let $$W_n=f(n)+f(n+1)+\ldots+f(2n)$$

and $$F(x)=\int_x^{2x} f(t)dt\;.$$

Prove that $$f(2n)\leq W_n-F(n)\leq f(n)$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

I have tried to make an inequality with $F(n)$ but I don't know what to use (mean value theorem or the fact that $f$ is decreasing).

Please help me to start.

Comment: This is basically the argument used to prove the integral convergence criteria in series. See for example Apostol, T. Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edition, Addison-Wesley, pp. 191.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $f$ is decreasing, you have for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and all $t\in[n,n+1]$:
$$f(n+1)\leqslant f(t)\leqslant f(n)$$

Just integrate each member of this double inequality on the interval $[n,n+1]$ and take the sum of each newly found member from $n$ to $2n-1$ and you should be fine.